# how to merge 2 input values in url

Tags: php, url, get, query-string

I have form like this

```
$A = isset( $_GET['first-name'] ) ? $_GET['first-name'] : '';
$B = isset( $_GET['last-name'] ) ? $_GET['last-name'] : '';

<form method ='get' >
<input type="text"  name="first-name" value="<?=$A?>" />
<input type="text" name="last-name" value="<?=$B?>" />
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
</form>
```

this what i get : www.website.com/some.php?first-name=Nick&last-name=Bill

How to merge two values in one name on submit in url like so - **www.website.com/some.php?first-name=Nick+Bill**

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following to get firstname and lastname in one field

```
<form method ='get' >
<input type="text"  name="first-name" value="<?=$A.' '.$B?>" />
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default"">
</form>
```

However,I think you should rename your "First-name" field to simple "name" as it is representing the complete name not just first name.

Comment: doesn't work , i get the same result

Comment: I dont believe.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you forgot to close the " after text
then, you simply concatenate the two values in one input

```
$A = isset( $_GET['first-name'] ) ? $_GET['search_title'] : '';
$B = isset( $_GET['last-name'] ) ? $_GET['search_title'] : '';

<form method ='get' >
<input type="text"  name="first-name" value="<?=$A+$B?>" />
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default"">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 steps involved in your question. First step is to merge to Variables in one. Second step is to Encode the variable to URL. Below is the solution

```
//First step to combine/merge 2 variables. This will be after you define $A and $B
$C = $A . ' ' . $B;

//Now encoding $C to URL
$D = urlencode($C);
```

Now you can simply use `$D` within a URL. This way you are not supposed to manually change spaces or any other such characters to URL-friendly codes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: doesn't work , i get the same result

Comment: Try to echo $A, $B, $C and $D. What do you get?

Comment: <input type="text"  name="first-name" value="<?=$D?>" />
<input type="text" name="last-name" value="<?=$B?>" />
i added $D and  i get this 
$A = nick
$B =rocky
$C =nick rocky
$D =nick+rocky
url - www.web.com/some.php?first-name=nick&last-name=rocky

Comment: Use this - http://www.website.com/some.php?first-name=<?php echo $D; ?>